# Array is defined in the function, but when returning it, it prints out undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

It is a coding challenge I am working on, when I console print out the array I get the correct answer, but when I return the value and console print it, it comes up as undefined. Can someone explain why that is and how to fix it. Thank You

```
function dirReduc(arr){
  var count = 0;
  for (i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
      if ((arr[i].toLowerCase() === 'south' && arr[i+1].toLowerCase() === 'north') || (arr[i].toLowerCase() === 'north' && arr[i+1].toLowerCase() === 'south')){
        arr.splice(i,2);
        console.log("northSouth");
      } else if ((arr[i].toLowerCase() === 'east' && arr[i+1].toLowerCase() === 'west') || (arr[i].toLowerCase() === 'west' && arr[i+1].toLowerCase() === 'east')){
        arr.splice(i,2);
        console.log("eastWest");
      } else {
        count++
        console.log(count);
      }
      console.log(arr);
  } 
  // console.log(count, i);
  if (count === i) {
    //console.log(arr);
    return arr;
  } else {
    dirReduc(arr);
  }
  
}

console.log(dirReduc(["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]));
```

Comment: since you're recursing ... `return dirReduc(arr);`

Comment: You forgot `return` before the recursive call, so when the function calls itself you don't return that result